# How do I create a summary data item in Cognos Report Studio?

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am working on a Cognos Report Studio Version 10 where I have to convert SQL code into Data Items. I have all the Columns required in the package to drag as Data Items in the query but I am stuck where there's calculated fields. This is one of them

> NET_ORIG_AMT  derived from 
>   (ORIG_  AMT)  – (PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT)

`ORIG_AMT` was derived from a simple `IF THEN ELSE` function and could be easily created as a calculated data item.
But `PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT` is coming from this SQL code:

```
SELECT          LEAD_ACCT, 
                PART_FLAG, 
                SUM (ORIG_AMT) AS PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT,                                                                                                   
FROM            TableName
GROUP BY        LEAD_ACCT, PART_FLAG
HAVING          PART_FLAG = 'Y'
```

How do I create a Data Item for `PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT`?

Pl note: I have `LEAD_ACCT, PART_FLAG` fields as calculated fields in the Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you help me understand how to write SUM (ORIG_AMT) AS PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT Group by LEAD_ACCT, PART_FLAG in Cognos Report Studio?

The equivalent in a Cognos expression would be:

```
total([ORIG_AMT] for [LEAD_ACCT],[PART_FLAG])
```

Answer (score 0):

3 choices:

1. Create a separate query in Cognos specifically for `PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT`. Join this query to your primary query on the appropriate fields and bring this in.
2. Create a query subject for `PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT` within the model itself, and do the above in  RS as described above. Preferred method if you are re-using this data item across reports.
3. Create a view in SQL which takes care of all of this special logic.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please be aware that I don't have access to Framework Manager. Even If I try to create separate query in RS, how can I still translate this code as a data item considering the fact that all the fields in the select statement are calculated fields?

Comment: Recreate them in the query or create derived queries where you progressively add more business logic.

Comment: Sorry not able to understand. I am very new to SQL coding and Cognos too. Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you help me understand how to write SUM (ORIG_AMT) AS PARTICIPATION_ORIG_AMT Group by LEAD_ACCT, PART_FLAG in Cognos Report Studio?